# Test if a website has responsive qualities

Tags: responsive-webdesign, testing

Within the context of a market study, I would like to determine if a website has responsiveness qualities.

Given an website URL, I would give a notation regarding these points:

good points:

- use of media-queries
- presence of a viewport tag

bad points:

- elements, fonts with static sizes

I do not want to test the design quality, nor the usability, just know if there has been a work done in that direction.

Do you see other things that makes obvious that a website has been build with responsivity in mind?

I want to make automated tests, so criterias should be simple.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is aimig at – and your question is also rather broad – *Responsive Design* is a wide field. You may also consider asking over at http://ux.stackexchange.com – I have the feeling you might get more suitable answers than here.

That said I'll try to answer: if you *just* want to check for 'responsiveness' (yes/no) then media queries are probably ***the*** criteria I would recommend looking at.

Basically *Responsive Design* just means, that the website design should adapt to different screen sizes. That *can* mean that the layout changes slightly according to screen sizes by rearranging layout elements or the like. It *can* however also mean that image sizes and/or font sizes change relative to the screen size / viewport size.

So following your question, I would probably just change the browser window size to see if anything changes. If in doubt, I would look at the css and check media queries.

What I would personally be interested in:

- Does the layout change according to screen sizes?
- Does the navigation adapt to the layout? How?
- Is the website layout still zoomable – or fixed?
- Are elements hidden to achieve a well-fitting layout? What elements?
- Are media elements e.g. video player and slide shows integrated mobile friendly? For example are HTML5 fall backs used for Adobe Flash Players?
- How are pop up windows / modal windows handled? Do they also adapt to screen size?
- Can the page be viewed in `Reader` mode? (iOS)
- Are form elements (textfields, buttons, …) 'mobile friendly'? Are HTML5 tags used that may (or may not) be supported by various mobile devices?

*…to be continued…*

Comment: Thank you for that list, even if some of these could be difficult to check programmaticaly.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's rather a question of 'how deep do you want to digg' than 'yes or no'

Comment: I want more to know if a website is clearly not responsive than if a good job has been done.

Comment: Then I guess changing the browser window size should do – at least if the layout *does* change then you know the wensite layout *is* reacting responsive to a certain degree… However It could still be considered *responsive* since there could be "device sniffers" or "screen size sniffers" and the like in the background that you would probably miss by simply resizing the browser window…

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the Google mobile friendly test is of use to your study. You can input a URL and the tool tests a variety of responsive parameters. The test also says which parameters have been tested and which have been found not responsive.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Comment: This could be ideal, but I am not sure that google will let me test thousands of websites.